# Single layer build file for a dojo/cordova project

Tags: javascript, cordova, dojo, dojox.mobile

I am using dojo 1.10 in a cordova v5 project.
I created the project and the build is successful.
It uses "android" platform and all files/folders are in the `assets/www`.
In there, I added "dojo", "dijit", "dojox" and some other folders like "js" and "widgets".

I am trying to find a way to build all the project into a single JavaScript file.

Any tutorial or videos will be helpful.

Comment: have a look at [dojo build](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a comprehensive tutorial at:

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/

and a useful dojo boilerplate at:

https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate

More details on how to setup your `.profile.js` can be found here:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/profiles.html

I would suggest you to read the articles and set your project following the `dojo-boilerplate` and after customize the build process from that, as sometime the build could be difficult to setup.